# How to implement key entries with PyGame?

Tags: python, pygame, key

Working on my first game project on Python with PyGame, I can't get any key entry to work.

I copied a (working) script that I have founded on the internet, and trying to modify it to my taste, here's what it looks like:

```
from pygame import *

knightpic = image.load('D:\\Game Dev\\Project 1 - Python\\knight01.png')

bushpic = image.load('D:\\Game Dev\\Project 1 - Python\\bush02.png')

done = False


kx = 500
ky = 400


bushx = 700
bushy = 600


init()
screen = display.set_mode((1000, 800))
display.set_caption('Protect the queen !')

while done == False:
    screen.fill(0)
    screen.blit(knightpic, (kx, ky))
    screen.blit(bushpic, (bushx, bushy))
    display.update()

    time.delay(1)


    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    if keys[K_LEFT]:
        bushx += 1
    if keys[K_RIGHT]:
        bushx -= 1
    if keys[K_DOWN]:
        bushy += 1
    if keys[K_UP]:
        bushy -= 1
```

(Sorry for the big code, I guess it is unnecessary but I'm not familiar with most of the fonctions used here so it might contain a problem I can't see.)

I did this last part myself, and wonder weither it is adapted or not to the rest. Goal is to make the bush move relatively to the knight.
When Ctrl+E I can see the little knight and the bush, but nothing when pressing keys.

Thank you by advance for reading (and answering if you feel like so).

Comment: Side notes: Don't use `from pygame import *` and rather `import pygame`. That helps to avoid bugs and is usually more readable.  Instead of `time.delay(1)` you should use a [`pygame.time.Clock`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock) and call its `tick` method every frame with the desired framerate as the argument (search for examples).

Comment: `import pygame` does not seem to work here. Besides I think I clearly lack some basics of this kind of algorithm. Would you mind explaining how the fonctions work ? `pygame.time.Clock` and `pygame.event.get()`.

Comment: You should create a clock instance before the main while loop: `clock = pygame.time.Clock()`. Then call `clock.tick(maximum_fps)` in your while loop to limit the game to the `maximum_fps` rate. That means your game won't run faster than for example 60 fps and won't take up more CPU power than needed.

Comment: Pygame has an event queue to which all produced events like "arrow key up" or mouse clicks are added. To loop over this event queue, you can write: `for event in pygame.event.get():` and can then handle one event after the other. Take a look at [Program Arcade Games](http://programarcadegames.com/index.php?lang=en&chapter=introduction_to_graphics) section 5.5.

Comment: Thank you this is very helpful. Yet before going any further my pyzo now starts returning `'pygame' is not defined` even though it starts the black window and all. (I still use `from pygame import *` but it looked like the only way which actually worked out). Any idea ?

Comment: @skrx Okay apparently I just need to `import pygame` through the shell everytime I reboot it (i.e. everytime I run the script). No more error message ! The knight won't move though. Will study this link you shared. Thank you again.

Comment: Hmm, you shouldn't have to `import pygame` in the shell, just in the script. BTW, you have to add `pygame.` before every pygame function call and constants like `pygame.K_LEFT` (instead of just `K_LEFT` (the same for the other keys)). What editor or IDE do you use?

Comment: Yes I got no more error now thank you (`import pygame` and `pygame.` before every function). I use pyzo (3.4), not sure it answers your question though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to process the events every frame. You can either use an event loop with [`pygame.event.get()`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.get) or call [`pygame.event.pump()`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.pump) every frame.

```
while not done:
    # Either use pygame.event.pump to clear the event queue ...
    # pygame.event.pump()

    # or use an event loop like this:
    for ev in pygame.event.get():
        # This allows you to press the 'X' to
        # quit the game and close the window.
        if ev.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True
```